# Virutalized List should never be nested with flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a flatlist and a footer like a chat app. I dont find any tutorials where I can make a fixed footer with "listedFooterComponent" so I made an view for this.

Now I have a textinput. I use keyboard-aware-scrollview because of the textinput, it works all fine but I get the error messages:

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
```

Code:

```
...
  const showFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={s.footerContainer}>
        <TextInput value={input} onChangeText={e => handleChangeInput(e)} multiline numberOfLines={4} style={s.footerInput} />
      </View>
    )
  };

 // console.log(message);
  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"}
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}
            behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "position" : null}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      
            contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={message}
        keyExtractor={i => i.id.toString()}
        renderItem={rowRenderer}
        initialNumToRender={4}
        windowSize={4}
        inverted
      />
      </View>
      <View style={s.footer}>
        { showFooter() }
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  )
};
```

Comment: You can't put a flatlist in a scrollview. Is the footer supposed to render at then end of the flatlist, or always at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @windowsill the footer is at the bottom of the screen like fixed. Like a chat application in whatsapp. If I dont use keyboardscrollview then my textinput looks confiused on focus and I got more problems

Comment: Have you tried `KeyboardAvoidingView`?